# Django update the user's rate

Tags: django, rating

im trying to implement rate system where user can rate (for example such person) only once, but he can change his rate.

```
class Rate(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('sender', 'person'),)

    choice = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, choices=RATE_CHOICES)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I found something like unique_together and it works - user can rate only once, but I have a problem with changing it.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        vote, created = Rate.objects.get_or_create(
                        sender=self.request.user, 
                        person=self.get_object(),
                        choice=form.cleaned_data['choice'])
                    

        if not created:
            Rate.objects.filter(sender=self.request.user, person=self.get_object()).update(choice=form.cleaned_data['choice'])
            return super(PersonDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(PersonDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I tried something like above but still getting

> UNIQUE constraint failed: main_rate.sender_id, main_rate.person_id

Comment: Exactly what sort of view do you use? A `CreateView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) will try te retrieve the item with the given filter, and if it can not find it, construct a new one. The problem is here that you filter on the `sender`, the `person`, *and* the `choice`, so if the `choice` is different than the one already saved, it will try to construct a new `Rate`, and thus the database will reject that.

You can make use of [**`update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) and thus specify the `choice` in the `defaults=…` parameter instead:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    Rate.objects.update_or_create(
        sender=self.request.user, 
        person=self.object,
        defaults={'choice': form.cleaned_data['choice']}
    )
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Note however that the `super().form_valid(form)` will try to save the form. It might thus be better to simply return a redirect to the success url:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class MyView(…):
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        Rate.objects.update_or_create(
            sender=self.request.user, 
            person=self.object,
            defaults={'choice': form.cleaned_data['choice']}
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly. I didn't hear about update_or_create. Btw: I use DetailView with FormMixin.